# WinForms Graphics PictureBox with dynamic width

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I'm making a winform .NET app. It must show a graphic in bars format. I'm using a picturebox because it's the only way I know how to do it (if someone knows a better way, please tell me).

I'm adding dynamically the lines (the bars of the graphic) with this code:

```
int currentX = this.lineAmmount * (lineWidth + lineMargin);
pictureBox.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(new Pen(color, lineWidth), //Pen
    currentX, pictureBox.Height, //Starting (x, y)
    currentX, pictureBox.Height - Convert.ToInt32(value * graphicsScale)); //Ending (x, y)
this.lineAmmount++;
```

That works just perfect.

What I want now is the pictureBox to have an horizontal scroll bar. So what I put the pictureBox into a panel with autoscroll = true. Now what I needed its to dynamically increase the pictureBox width. So I added this code after I add each line:

```
pictureBox.Width = Math.Max(this.lineAmmount * (lineWidth + lineMargin), 205);
```

(205 is the minimum width I want).

That code also works greate. The width is increased. With the first lines Math.Max always returns 205, after a couple of lines it starts returning the orher value. From that moment on ALL THE LINES DISAPPEAR!!!

Please help!!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english,

Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the Chart control. It does all that automatically.

Comment: looks like you answered your question then.

Answer (score 0):

Where is written that code, that you posted in first box? Is it in update method of the control?

Sure, chart will be more appropriate here